# How do I make the minimumFontSize property work for a multiline label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, font-size, multiline

how do I make the [minimumFontSize](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) property work for a multiline label. The documentation says it must have 1 line. Are there any workarounds. I have label with a primary purpose to display short texts like this: `-20%` or `+30%` etc, but this is not enforced and there are ocasionally longer texts like `Free cookies` and I want to resize font but also have multiple lines. Like this:

```
+----------+
|   Free   |
| Cookies! |
+----------+
```

The label must always have the same size because it is transparent and has a fixed size image underneath it. Is it possible? The part where the users enter these data is not under my control, it is a web app, and I'm an iPhone using a webservice. This is still short enough for web but not for iPhone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Resize Multi-line Text to Fit UILabel on iPhone](http://www.11pixel.com/blog/28/resize-multi-line-text-to-fit-uilabel-on-iphone/), this might help.